# Why am I getting an ORA-00937 error?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

This is my oracle query:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT Student.student_id, student_name, SUM(credit)
FROM        Student, Class, Enrolls
WHERE       Student.student_id = Enrolls.student_id
AND         Class.schedule_num = Enrolls.schedule_num
AND         Class.semester = Enrolls.semester
AND         grade != 'F'
AND         grade IS NOT null
ORDER BY    student_id ASC;
```

The query worked fine until I added `SUM(credit)`. After that I get:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you are missing the `GROUP BY` clause in your SQL statement.  It should look something like:

```
SELECT      Student.student_id, student_name, SUM(credit)
FROM        Student, Class, Enrolls
WHERE       Student.student_id = Enrolls.student_id
AND         Class.schedule_num = Enrolls.schedule_num
AND         Class.semester = Enrolls.semester
AND         grade != 'F'
AND         grade IS NOT null
GROUP BY    Student.student_id, student_name
ORDER BY    student_id ASC;
```

Comment: The GROUP BY would also make the use of DISTINCT unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT      DISTINCT s.student_id, student_name, SUM(credit)
FROM        Student s, 
            CLASS c, 
            Enrolls e
WHERE       s.student_id = e.student_id
AND         c.schedule_num = e.schedule_num
AND         c.semester = e.semester
AND         grade != 'F'
AND         grade IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    s.student_id, student_name
ORDER BY    student_id ASC;
```

You have missed `GROUP BY` clause in you query, If you want the sum the credit, you need to group by student_id & student_name.